# only update value if not empty $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

i have 4 variable like this :

```
$a = $_POST['a'];    //1
$b = $_POST['b'];    //
$c = $_POST['c'];    //
$d = $_POST['d'];   // 5
```

currently mysql work that catch all value from input:

```
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key IN(rate1,rate2,rate3,rate4) AND post_id=".$_POST['postid']);  
$wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta  (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($_POST['postid'],rate1,$a),($_POST['postid'],rate2,$b),($_POST['postid'],rate3,$c),($_POST['postid'],rate4,$d) ");
```

Is there anyway that reduce query that only insert/delete when $_POST not null . Current i check if  $_POST not null , i will run delete/insert once . It make my code very long because i must check both a,b,c,d then insert/delete

```
if($a != ""){
  $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key=rate1 AND post_id=".$_POST['postid']);  
$wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta  (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES ($_POST['postid'],rate1,$a) ");
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection. Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: If you can refactor your input into an array, you'll find it a lot easier to work with. If you've got variables named after numbers or letters, that's a good sign that you should be using an array instead.

Comment: this code just a simple code i write for an advise , not real code in my project :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $errors = false;
    $fields = array("a","b","c","d");

    foreach($fields as $fieldname){

        if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])){

            $errors = true;

            echo "enter ".$_POST[$fieldname];
        }
    }
    if(!$errors){
        $a = $_POST['a'];    //1
        $b = $_POST['b'];    //
        $c = $_POST['c'];    //
        $d = $_POST['d'];   // 5


        //  DO your queries

    }
?>
```

Take care of the sql injections

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be sth that you are looking for:

```
if (isset($_POST)){
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your original code, PHP will throw a notice if any of the four variables isn't set (you're trying to access an array index that doesn't exist).

To conform to the `fail-fast` principle, you'd want to elevate that notice to the status of an exception, by having the following code somewhere high in the hierarchy (PHP7+ code, but PHP5+ code is available in the bottom link).

```
set_error_handler(function($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
    throw new Exception($message);
});
```

This way, whenever you're trying to read a POST variable that hasn't been set, execution won't move forward with incomplete data. You will need to do a try/catch to gracefully handle that exception.

PHP5+ code: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/error-reporting-exception-handlers-php/